# Porting Xamarin Windows 8 app to Windows 10 SDK

Tags: c#, xamarin

I'm trying to run one of samples [from this site](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples).

The problem is: projects were made for Windows 8. When I open solution in Visual Studio, it tells me that I need to install Windows 8 SDK to proceed.

[image]

I'm using now Windows 10 SDK and I will no longer use SDK 8, so I'd rather not install this SDK and use new one intead. Can I somehow port this project to Windows 10 app?

How it looks like right now:

[image]

Comment: Are you looking to add UWP (Universal Windows Platform)? This tutorial should help you get started: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/platform-features/windows/installation/universal/. It looks like that tutorial is Xamarin Forms based, so it should work fine with UWP if you use a recent version of Xamarin Forms.

Comment: I know it's been a while since I asked this question, but I came back to this problem and it is still not solved. Your comment is not exactly what I asked for, you might not understand me correctly. I've updated question with some more details.

Comment: Do you use Visual Studio 2013 or 2015?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, porting is possible. I would suggest creating a new project in this solution (most solutions of this git already added UWP support, as I saw) and redo most stuff. On some projects which use platform specific code, this porting might not work since some APIs changed from WP8 to UWP - as you probably know.

After this procedure I still had problems - I had no working .appxmanifest file, so I cannot create a .pfx file. This keeps warning you the certifcate file is missing.

I am not sure if all steps are necessary. I leave this as homework ;)

Anyway, here I show you steps to port the TodoREST-project to UWP:

- Unloading iOS and Droid project will make this easier
- Uninstall all nuget packages from Portable and WinPhone81 project
- Change portable class profile to Profile111 (uncheck WP8 Silverlight as target)
- Now you can reinstall Xamarin.Forms and Newtonsoft.Json on portable project (uninstall was necessary to change profile - which was necessary because it raised some errors here)
- Remove app.config from WinPhone81 project
- Add a `project.json` file to WinPhone81 project and put in following content:

  ```
  {
      "dependencies": {
          "Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform": "5.0.0",
          "Xamarin.Forms": "2.0.0.6482"
      },
      "frameworks": {
          "uap10.0": { }
      },
      "runtimes": {
          "win10-arm": { },
          "win10-arm-aot": { },
          "win10-x86": { },
          "win10-x86-aot": { },
          "win10-x64": { },
          "win10-x64-aot": { }
      }
  }
  ```
- Save everything and close WinPhone81 project
- In file explorer go to folder and edit Package.appxmanifest

  - Exchange Package Tag by following:

    ```
    <Package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10" xmlns:mp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/phone/manifest" xmlns:m3="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10" IgnorableNamespaces="m3 mp">
    ```
  - Remove ... and add following instead:

    ```
    <Dependencies>
        <TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Universal" MinVersion="10.0.0.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.0.0"/>
    </Dependencies>
    ```
- Edit TodoREST.WinPhone81.csproj:

  - In first `<PropertyGroup>` replace `<TargetPlatformVersion>` by this:

    ```
    <TargetPlatformIdentifier>UAP</TargetPlatformIdentifier>
    <TargetPlatformVersion>10.0.10586.0</TargetPlatformVersion>
    <TargetPlatformMinVersion>10.0.10586.0</TargetPlatformMinVersion>
    ```
  - Change `ProjectTypeGuids` to

    ```
    <ProjectTypeGuids>{A5A43C5B-DE2A-4C0C-9213-0A381AF9435A};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>
    ```
  - On every `PropertyGroup` with `Condition=...` replace `WINDOWS_PHONE_APP` in DefineConstants by `WINDOWS_UAP`
  - Save
- Reload project in Visual Studio
- Edit MainPage.xaml and change `<forms:WindowsPhonePage` to `<forms:WindowsPage` and forms namespace to `using:Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP` (from `.WinRT`)
- Here I had to restart VS2015 for any reason as it did not notice the project.json
- *Start project and debug!*

I hope this answers your questions.